# Syntax error in SAP Hana when changing to a variable input [%0] SAP B1 v9.3 using Query Manager

Tags: hana, sapb1

--Here is the query. when i make T0."ItemCode" = 'HN 210' in the query (all places) it -----works fine.  When I change the where segment to Where T0."ItemCode" = [%0] is when I get --the error

```
Select  a.*,b."OldPrice" from (
Select 'm' as "type", T0."ItemCode" , T2."ItemName" , T7."ListName" , T0."Price" as 
"NewPrice" , 
T2."UpdateDate" , '9999999' as "code" , T5."U_NAME" , T2."U_lastpriceupdate", 
T2."CreateDate"
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T2."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = [%0] and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5')
UNION ALL
Select 'a' as "type", T0."ItemCode" , T2."ItemName", T7."ListName" , T1."Price" as 
"NewPrice",
T4."UpdateDate" , T1."LogInstanc" as "code" , T5."U_NAME" , T2."U_lastpriceupdate", 
T2."CreateDate" 
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
inner join AIT1 T1 on T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T0."PriceList" = 
T1."PriceList"
INNER JOIN AITM T4 on T4."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T1."LogInstanc" = 
T4."LogInstanc"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T4."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = [%0] and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5')
order by "type" desc, "code" desc) as a
LEFT JOIN
(Select 'a' as "type", T0."ItemCode" , T2."ItemName", T7."ListName" , T1."Price" as 
"OldPrice" ,
T4."UpdateDate" , '9999999' as "code"  , T5."U_NAME" , T2."U_lastpriceupdate", 
T2."CreateDate" 
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
inner join AIT1 T1 on T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T0."PriceList" = 
T1."PriceList"
INNER JOIN AITM T4 on T4."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T1."LogInstanc" = 
T4."LogInstanc"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T4."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = [%0] and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5') and T1."LogInstanc" IN (
Select max(T1."LogInstanc") as "t"
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
inner join AIT1 T1 on T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T0."PriceList" = 
T1."PriceList"
INNER JOIN AITM T4 on T4."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T1."LogInstanc" = 
T4."LogInstanc"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T4."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = [%0] and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5')
GROUP BY T0."ItemCode" )
UNION ALL
Select 'a' as "type", T0."ItemCode" , T2."ItemName", T7."ListName" , T1."Price" as 
"OldPrice" ,
 T4."UpdateDate" , (T1."LogInstanc")+1 as "code"  , T5."U_NAME" , 
T2."U_lastpriceupdate", T2."CreateDate" 
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
inner join AIT1 T1 on T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T0."PriceList" = 
T1."PriceList"
INNER JOIN AITM T4 on T4."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T1."LogInstanc" = 
T4."LogInstanc"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T4."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = [%0] and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5')
order by "type" desc, "code" desc
) as b

on a."ItemCode" = b."ItemCode" and b."code" = a."code"
Where a."NewPrice" <> b."OldPrice" 
order by a."type" desc, a."code" desc
```

--I have noticed in other places where a variable in a nested query may not work.  As may --be the case here.  Any solutions on how to get this to accept a variable item code? i did find this link related to setting up a declare to name the variable. But I do not have the syntax correct to get it to work.
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/04/01/working-with-sql-query-generator-variables/

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, I had to comment out the 2 inner **Order By** as we are using microsoft Sql Server and the Syntax may be different for HANA.

User Parameter can give some very strange errors but the top 4 lines will link it to an SAP table (Item Master in this case) and should solve the problem.

```
/* SELECT FROM [dbo].[OITM] T0 */
DECLARE @Product AS nvarchar(20)
/* WHERE */
SET @Product = /* T0.ItemCode */ '[%0]'


Select  a.*,b."OldPrice" from (
Select 'm' as "type", T0."ItemCode" , T2."ItemName" , T7."ListName" , T0."Price" as 
"NewPrice" , 
T2."UpdateDate" , '9999999' as "code" , T5."U_NAME" , 
T2."CreateDate"
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T2."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = @Product and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5')
UNION ALL
Select 'a' as "type", T0."ItemCode" , T2."ItemName", T7."ListName" , T1."Price" as 
"NewPrice",
T4."UpdateDate" , T1."LogInstanc" as "code" , T5."U_NAME" , 
T2."CreateDate" 
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
inner join AIT1 T1 on T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T0."PriceList" = 
T1."PriceList"
INNER JOIN AITM T4 on T4."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T1."LogInstanc" = 
T4."LogInstanc"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T4."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = @Product and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5')
--order by "type" desc, "code" desc
) as a
LEFT JOIN
(Select 'a' as "type", T0."ItemCode" , T2."ItemName", T7."ListName" , T1."Price" as 
"OldPrice" ,
T4."UpdateDate" , '9999999' as "code"  , T5."U_NAME" , 
T2."CreateDate" 
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
inner join AIT1 T1 on T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T0."PriceList" = 
T1."PriceList"
INNER JOIN AITM T4 on T4."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T1."LogInstanc" = 
T4."LogInstanc"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T4."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = @Product and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5') and T1."LogInstanc" IN (
Select max(T1."LogInstanc") as "t"
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
inner join AIT1 T1 on T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T0."PriceList" = 
T1."PriceList"
INNER JOIN AITM T4 on T4."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T1."LogInstanc" = 
T4."LogInstanc"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T4."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = @Product and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5')
GROUP BY T0."ItemCode" )
UNION ALL
Select 'a' as "type", T0."ItemCode" , T2."ItemName", T7."ListName" , T1."Price" as 
"OldPrice" ,
 T4."UpdateDate" , (T1."LogInstanc")+1 as "code"  , T5."U_NAME" , 
 T2."CreateDate" 
FROM
OITM T2
Inner Join ITM1 T0 on T0."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode"
inner join AIT1 T1 on T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T0."PriceList" = 
T1."PriceList"
INNER JOIN AITM T4 on T4."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode" and T1."LogInstanc" = 
T4."LogInstanc"
INNER JOIN OUSR T5 on T5."INTERNAL_K" = T4."UserSign2"
Inner join OPLN T7 on T0."PriceList" = T7."ListNum"
Where T0."ItemCode" = @Product and 
T0."PriceList" IN ('5')
--order by "type" desc , "code" desc
) as b

on a."ItemCode" = b."ItemCode" and b."code" = a."code"
Where a."NewPrice" <> b."OldPrice" 
order by a."type" desc, a."code" desc
```